# Spring Boot Test: Unknown Entity when using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot

Following along on a theme of questions related to Spring Boot. I am trying to set up a an integration test with the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestApplicationConfig.class,TestPersistenceConfig.class,MvcConfig.class,SecurityConfig.class},loader=AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ApplicationIntegrationTest {

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    //@Resource(name="springSecurityFilterChain")
    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDao clientDao;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        // using the web application to initate the mock
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();

        // here we should build up the data structure using hibernate
        List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();

        Client clientEN = new Client();
        clientEN.setDeviceId("444444444");
        clientEN.setLanguage("en-EN");
        clientEN.setAgentId("444444444|68:5b:35:8a:7c:d0");
        Client clientENDomain = clientDao.save(clientEN);
        clients.add(clientENDomain);

        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
        Role roleUser = new Role();
        roleUser.setRole("user");
        Role roleUserDomain = roleDao.save(roleUser);
        roles.add(roleUserDomain);

        Role roleAdmin = new Role();
        roleAdmin.setRole("admin");
        Role roleAdminDomain = roleDao.save(roleAdmin);
        roles.add(roleAdminDomain);

        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin("user");
        user.setPassword("password");
        user.setClients(clients);
        user.setRoles(roles);

        userDao.save(user);

    }

    @Test
    public void thatViewBootstrapUsesHttpNotFound() throws Exception {

        // testing that a correct login into the form will result in a cookie being set
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/login")
                .param("username", "user").param("password", "password")).andReturn();
        Cookie c = result.getResponse().getCookie("my-cookie");

        Cookie[] cookies = result.getResponse().getCookies();
        for (int i = 0; i <= cookies.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("cookie " + i + " name: " + cookies[i].getName());
            System.out.println("cookie " + i + " value: " + cookies[i].getValue());
        }
        //assertThat(c.getValue().length(), greaterThan(10));

        // No cookie; 401 Unauthorized
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());

        // With cookie; 200 OK
        mockMvc.perform(get("/").cookie(c)).andExpect(status().isOk());

        // Logout, and ensure we're told to wipe the cookie
        result = mockMvc.perform(delete("/session")).andReturn();
        c = result.getResponse().getCookie("my-cookie");
        assertThat(c.getValue().length(), is(0));
    }
}
```

The test application config is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.touchcorp.touchpoint"})
public class TestApplicationConfig {
}
```

and the TestPersistenceConfig is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.touchcorp.touchpoint.model"})
public class TestPersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory( emf );
        return transactionManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource( hsqlDataSource() );
        emf.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.touchcorp.touchppoint.model" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        emf.setJpaProperties( buildHibernateProperties() );

       return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource hsqlDataSource()
    {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("classpath:schema.sql")
            .build();

    }

    protected Properties buildHibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "false");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

Here is the Client model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="client")
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="deviceId")
    private String deviceId;

    @Column(name = "language")
    private String language;

    @Column(name = "agentId")
    private String agentId;

    @Column(name = "token")
    private String token;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "expiry")
    private Date expiry;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="client_role",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private List<Role> roles;

    @ManyToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "clients", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getAgentId() {
        return agentId;
    }

    public void setAgentId(String agentId) {
        this.agentId = agentId;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public Date getExpiry() {
        return expiry;
    }

    public void setExpiry(Date expiry) {
        this.expiry = expiry;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

and here's the error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown entity: com.touchcorp.touchpoint.model.domain.Client; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.touchcorp.touchpoint.model.domain.Client
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:157)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.touchcorp.touchpoint.application.ApplicationIntegrationTest.setup(ApplicationIntegrationTest.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.touchcorp.touchpoint.model.domain.Client
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1184)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.persist(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:262)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.touchcorp.touchpoint.model.dao.ClientDaoImpl.save(ClientDaoImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 35 more
```

I have spent a lot of time trawling around to find the right combination of annotations to solve the general application booting. It appears that everything on the classpath is being picked up now, but it seems that spring boot is not somehow making the @Entites available to hibernate/JPA.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled "touchpoint" as "touchppoint" in the EMF configuration.

Comment: I must both thank you and apologise for wasting your time. I also found out that I need to additionally add the @Transactional annotation to the unit test - and away it went!

Comment: At least the configuration above should be a nice concise guide to others to getting spring boot jpa and hibernate to play nicely together.

Comment: Cool. It didn't really waste any time. The "Unknown entity" means that JPA isn't scanning the entities in question so I knew where to look. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this error (org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown entity) just only by setting the exact package location (com.myorg.myentities) where all my Java entities resides:

entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(Entities package location)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I forgot to set the ID of my Entity.